# What are my options for dealing with an unbalanced data set in keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm learning keras by going through the IMDB review classification problem

```
import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
import os


# load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 5000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)

# truncate and pad input sequences
max_review_length = 100
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)

# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

I'm wondering, aside from only picking the top proportion of words, what do the community recommend as other options for improving unbalanced data sets?

Just picking the top n words seems kind of (1) arbitrary and (2) you could be losing info (e.g. maybe the 5001th most common word would help the model).

I'm wondering what other options are out there, or is a general agreement to say pick N so it covers X% of the data (and if so, what is that X% that is generally used?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For word imbalance,

1. Just picking top N words is never a good idea.

In the dataset, the chances are the top N words will be `the`, `a`, `an`, etc. and these are just noise without any meaningful context.

2. Start by removing stop words to reduce the vocabulary size.

`print(stopwords.words('english'))`

https://stackabuse.com/removing-stop-words-from-strings-in-python/

Now, for class imbalance, there are already many established approaches like under sampling, over sampling, augmentation, etc.